# Python get instance from list based on instance variable

Tags: python, list, instances

Given a list of instances, say `clients` I'm trying to pluck an item from the list based on the value of a single instance variable `screenName`. I know I can do this:

```
for client in clients:
  if client.screenName = search:
    return client
```

But is there a nicer way of doing this without the loop?

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: I suppose you mean client.screen == search

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `filter`

```
try:
    filter(lambda client: client.screenName == search, clients)[0]
except IndexError:
    # handle error. May be use a default value
```

Comment: Won't this raise `IndexError` if **no** client in clients has `screenName == search` ? ...

Comment: @neurino I kind of assumed that the exception would be handled. But added the `try-except` block for sake of completeness.

Comment: I'd simply remove the `[0]` and return a list of results. After all there could be more than one match, then if only the first is needed...

Answer (score 1):

I would use [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). Suppose this is your `Client` class:

```
>>> class Client:
...    def __init__(self, screenName):
...        self.screenName = screenName
```

If I got this list of clients:

```
>>> l = [Client('a'), Client('b'), Client('c')]
```

...I can get a list containing only the clients with a given name:

```
>>> [e for e in l if e.screenName == 'b']
[<__main__.Client instance at 0x2e52b0>]
```

Now, just get the first - and assumedly only - element:

```
>>> [e for e in l if e.screenName == 'b'][0]
<__main__.Client instance at 0x2e52b0>
>>> c = [e for e in l if e.screenName == 'b'][0]
>>> c.screenName
'b'
```

This is pretty short and IMHO elegant but can be less efficient because the list comprehension will iterate over all the list. If you do want to avoid this overhead, you can get an generator instead of a new list using parenthesis instead of square brackets:

```
>>> g = (e for e in l if e.screenName == 'b')
>>> g
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x2e5440>
>>> g.next()
<__main__.Client instance at 0x2e52b0>
```

However, note that the `next()` method can be called just once.

HTH!

Comment: Very concise and nice. I assume next() can be called multiple times if l contains multiple objects with the same screenName.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [generator expression](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions),

```
client=next(client for client in clients if client.screenName == search)
```

but not that you still looping, just in a different way.

Note: If no client satisfies the condition `client.screenName == search` then the above will raise a `StopIteration` exception. This is different than your `for-loop`, which falls out of the loop without returning anything.

Depending on your situation, raising an exception might be better than failing silently.

If you do not want a default value instead of a `StopIteration` exception, then you could use the 2-parameter version of `next`:

```
client=next(client for client in clients if client.screenName == search, 
            default_value)
```

Answer (score 0):

using a dictionary for this:

assuming this :

```
d[screeName] = client
```

you can just do this:

```
return d[search]
```

Answer (score 0):

If `clients` is a `dict` then you can just use `clients[search]`. If the order of elements in your list is important, then you can use an `OrderedDict` from `collections`.

Answer (score 0):

Best discussion of this topic is on this [link](http://tomayko.com/writings/cleanest-python-find-in-list-function)

```
return find(lambda client: client.screenName == search, clients)
```

This requires you define a generic find function which would work for all types of lists like thus:

```
def find(f, seq):
  """Return first item in sequence where f(item) == True."""
  for item in seq:
    if f(item): 
      return item
```

Comment: I think you mean `s/find/filter/`?

Comment: no i meant what i wrote, dont get the downvote.  See here: http://tomayko.com/writings/cleanest-python-find-in-list-function